# Network with 3 locations connected through VPN; beginner

Tags: vpn

I already asked this question but i did not provide enough info, i am sorry for that so i drew a schematic of the network.

I am a student IT (networks) first year, and i am making a fictional network (doesn't exist). It's 2 stores and a main office which i want to connect trough VPN. I decided to put the main infrastructure at the main office AKA Site1. The idea is that the clients in the locations do not see each other. They will all need to be able to access the SQL server and file server at Site1.

So i guess my question is, is the network i have drawn possible?

I still a beginner and have no real experience designing networks, i hope i have provided enough information. I will add a drawing of my network below

[image]

Comment: In the future, please edit your existing question and add a comment asking for it to be re-opened.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's certainly possible. If I were to make some recommendations for improvements/corrections, they would be:

- Don't use adjacent `/24` networks. If one site grows larger than 254 hosts or needs to be split up into multiple subnets, you're sunk. Allocate at least a `/22` for each site, even if you'll only use a `/24` initially.
- You have multiple devices in each network assigned to the same IP address. This most certainly **will not** work.
- You don't specify where DNS services reside - you're going to need some sort of DNS resolvers and most likely recursive resolvers. Ideally you'll have at least one DNS server per site.

Comment: I think those multiple devices on one ip is just a type, he supposed to write 3.0 instead of 0.3

Comment: ja sorry i did not mean that i would use multiple devices on the same ip when i write 192.168.2.0 i mean it will be in the .2 range ofc all the device will get a diffirent ip

Comment: also at site 1 i have a primaryDC and secondary DC, is it really necessary to have a DNS on each site? can they not just all use the same domain?

Comment: DNS provides different functionality than "which domain they are in". If you're okay with network activity grinding to a halt when/if the VPN tunnel goes down, then all you need is a single server (well preferrably two servers) at the main site.

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget to mark answers as accepted if you're happy with them.